# If teacher punishing student is also supposed bad karma?

Tags: karma, teachers

Either school teacher or Buddhist teacher in monastery, if they would punish their students is also supposed bad karma even if it cause of bad behavior of students?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buddha did not do any violence. The suttas say:

> it is true, Kesi, that it's not proper for a Tathagata to take life. But if a tamable person doesn't submit either to a mild training or to a harsh training or to a mild & harsh training, then the Tathagata doesn't regard him as being worth speaking to or admonishing.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. @Dhammadhatu has read the full content of that sutta and answered the question, while the accepted answer is given just by reading the part of the sutta, and assuming 'kill him' means the death of that person. This is what has been happening to the real Dhamma for long time....

Comment: Hi Isuru It is up to people to get the full story without relying on a half story.

Comment: obviously your post was wrong. i suggest to make your non-dhamma posts on DW, where people are kind enough to not "kill" you and have extended discussion with you; attempting to patiently guide you to the True Dhamma. this forum, BSE, is for high quality answers, which is why i have over 30,000 merit points. with metta

Comment: @SarathW Hi, It seems like your intention was to get readers to read the full content and understand what you imply by the part of the answer. But as I mentioned it's misguiding. So I thought of adding a comment for readers who would mis guide this would think twice and get to the full answer. And I suggest updating that bit in the answer would stop misguiding the readers, as that is the accepted answer..!
With metta..!

Comment: Thanks your answer is more clear you have quoted right lines from sutta while @SarathW answer did confused me.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you punish. Buddha also punished.

=============

"If a tamable person doesn't submit either to a mild training or to a harsh training or to a mild & harsh training, then I kill him, Kesi."

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.111.than.html

Comment: Thanks I had to ask if Buddha ever punished someone else.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call that "punishment". I think that "punishment" is intended to change someone's behaviour, for example, "you committed a crime so I punish you now, if you commit another crime I will punish you again, because I want you to stop committing crimes in order to avoid being punished" -- which that "killing" isn't.

Comment: Kill means Buddha ignored the student

Comment: This answer is completely wrong and misguiding. Buddha may have punished, but that's only to show the path to Nirvana, but buddha never made someone killed, because according to buddha human life is very rare thing to be. This answer is not correct. This is an example to misinterpretations of dhamma meaning in cannon.

Comment: @Isuru I don't think anyone misinterprets this -- the "killing" is obviously a metaphor isn't it, not literal -- the literal meaning is, "don't regard him as being worth speaking to or admonishing"

Comment: @Isuru Also I'm not sure that what SarathW here calls punishment is "to show the path to Nirvana" -- instead the so-called "killing" might be because, if that student doesn't "submit to [any kinds of] training", then they just can't be trained.

Comment: @ChrisW: I totally understand what you meant. But all due respect, it seems like you haven't mine. I'm not trying regard anyone (you meant by `him`) to the misinterpretations. But trying to explain that this is the nature of the world, people understand with the context they are in or with the understanding they do have. And that's not the Dhamma. So we must be very careful when following someone's answers or comments on dhamma, and also when answering a questions too...

Answer (score 0):

> If teacher punishing student is also supposed bad karma?

It depends on thoughts `Chethanaham bikkawe kamman wadami` (question on this can be found [here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/14158/thought-or-intention-is-always-karma)). And only teacher knows what kind of thoughts were on his mind at that time.

> Either school teacher or Buddhist teacher in monastery, if they would
>   punish their students is also supposed bad karma even if it cause of
>   bad behavior of students?

As said above, it doesn't matter from the student's side, it matters from teacher's side, because he owns his karma as a return to his own actions.

Answer (score 0):

We donot know karma  and it's fruit.
We aren't buddha.
So this question is not right .
If I give any answer for this question. 
I will give wrong answer beacuse I do not know  karma..
I gave  answer  from memory. 
Book memory .
Buddha memory..
Memory can not give right answer.
My experience not book answer .
If I punish any student..if I feel guilt for punishment. 
 This is Not right.
This is my anger.
Angry man can't kind speech. 
This is voilence both inner voilence and outer voilence for students.

Answer (score -1):

Once a general asked buddha shouldnt criminals be punished
The Buddha replied: "He who deserves punishment must be punished, and he who is worthy of favor must be favored. Yet at the same time he teaches to do no injury to any living being but to be full of love and kindness. These injunctions are not contradictory, for whosoever must be punished for the crimes which he has committed, suffers his injury not through the ill-will of the judge but on account of his evil-doing. His own acts have brought upon him the injury that the executer of the law inflicts. When a magistrate punishes, let him not harbor hatred in his breast, yet a murderer, when put do death, should consider that this is the fruit of his own act. As soon as he will understand that the punishment will purify his soul, he will no longer lament his fate but rejoice at it."

Comment: Where is this quote from? It seems to be from [The Gospel of Buddha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gospel_of_Buddha), which is quite an unreliable source/author, isn't it?